How do I resolve ncurses build error in source file generated by MKlib_gen.sh
I am in the process of upgrading to bluez-5.65.tar.gz as part of a linux development build for a target arm-none-linux-gnueabi processor. This is simplified by dropping readline with --disable-client in the bluez spec however this comes at a cost because bluetoothctl is also dropped. Re-including readline leads to dependencies on other packages. This leads to undefined references to `tgetent', for example. It would seem that libtinfo is installed as part of ncurses, to resolve this. A sample spec file ncurses.spec is provided with reference to a very early version, namely ncurses-5.3.tar.gz. This was downloaded from the ncurses website https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#other_versions, along with the associated path file patch-5.3-5.4.sh.gz located here https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#where_patches. I was able to apply the patches successfully using the given example.
For the moment I have disabled PKG_LIBTERMCAP, though I assume I may need to revert this setting at some stage.
config PKG_NCURSES
    #select PKG_LIBTERMCAP
    bool "ncurses"
    help
      The curses library routines are a terminal-independent method of
      updating character screens with reasonable optimization. The ncurses
      (new curses) library is a freely distributable replacement for the
      discontinued 4.4BSD classic curses library.

This generates the following error in the source file ../ncurses/comp_captab.c, which is in fact generated by the ncurses script MKlib_gen.sh. How do I resolve this please?  Many thanks.
Build error:
`+ make -j1 'HOSTCC=ccache /usr/bin/gcc -B/usr/bin/'
cd man && make DESTDIR="/home/pgroves/workspace/RELEASE5301.orig/Eagle-Ltib/tmp/ncurses" all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pgroves/workspace/RELEASE5301.orig/Eagle-Ltib/rpm/BUILD/ncurses-5.3/man'
sh ./MKterminfo.sh ./terminfo.head ./../include/Caps ./terminfo.tail >terminfo.5
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pgroves/workspace/RELEASE5301.orig/Eagle-Ltib/rpm/BUILD/ncurses-5.3/man'
cd include && make DESTDIR="/home/pgroves/workspace/RELEASE5301.orig/Eagle-Ltib/tmp/ncurses" all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pgroves/workspace/RELEASE5301.orig/Eagle-Ltib/rpm/BUILD/ncurses-5.3/include'
cat curses.head >curses.h
AWK=mawk sh ./MKkey_defs.sh ./Caps >>curses.h
sh -c 'if test "chtype" = "cchar_t" ; then cat ./curses.wide >>curses.h ; fi'
cat ./curses.tail >>curses.h
mawk -f MKterm.h.awk ./Caps > term.h
sh ./edit_cfg.sh ../include/ncurses_cfg.h term.h
** edit: HAVE_TCGETATTR 1
** edit: HAVE_TERMIOS_H 1
** edit: HAVE_TERMIO_H 1
** edit: BROKEN_LINKER 0
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pgroves/workspace/RELEASE5301.orig/Eagle-Ltib/rpm/BUILD/ncurses-5.3/include'
cd ncurses && make DESTDIR="/home/pgroves/workspace/RELEASE5301.orig/Eagle-Ltib/tmp/ncurses" all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pgroves/workspace/RELEASE5301.orig/Eagle-Ltib/rpm/BUILD/ncurses-5.3/ncurses'
sh ./base/MKlib_gen.sh "gcc -E -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG" "mawk" generated <../include/curses.h | \
    fgrep undef >../include/nomacros.h
sh ./base/MKlib_gen.sh "gcc -E -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG" "mawk" generated <../include/curses.h >lib_gen.c
sh ./base/MKlib_gen.sh "gcc -E -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG" "mawk" implemented <../include/curses.h >link_test.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./tty/hashmap.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_beep.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_color.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_endwin.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_flash.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/lib_gen.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_getstr.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_mouse.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./tty/lib_mvcur.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_newterm.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_restart.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_screen.c
../ncurses/./base/lib_screen.c: In function 'getwin':
../ncurses/./base/lib_screen.c:48:5: warning: ignoring return value of 'fread', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     (void) fread(&tmp, sizeof(WINDOW), 1, filep);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../ncurses/./base/lib_screen.c:95:6: warning: ignoring return value of 'fread', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
      (void) fread(nwin->_line[n].text,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     sizeof(NCURSES_CH_T),
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     (size_t) (nwin->_maxx + 1),
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     filep);
     ~~~~~~
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_set_term.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_slk.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_slkrefr.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./tty/lib_vidattr.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./tty/tty_update.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/lib_dft_fgbg.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./tinfo/lib_print.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/resizeterm.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./base/wresize.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./tinfo/alloc_entry.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/./tinfo/alloc_ttype.c
cd ../obj_s;  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -c ../ncurses/comp_captab.c
../ncurses/comp_captab.c: In function '_nc_get_table':
../ncurses/comp_captab.c:74:19: error: '_nc_cap_table' undeclared (first use in this function)
  return termcap ? _nc_cap_table: _nc_info_table ;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../ncurses/comp_captab.c:74:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../ncurses/comp_captab.c:74:34: error: '_nc_info_table' undeclared (first use in this function)
  return termcap ? _nc_cap_table: _nc_info_table ;
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [Makefile:974: ../obj_s/comp_captab.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pgroves/workspace/RELEASE5301.orig/Eagle-Ltib/rpm/BUILD/ncurses-5.3/ncurses'
make: *** [Makefile:96: all] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /home/pgroves/workspace/RELEASE5301.orig/Eagle-Ltib/tmp/rpm-tmp.48770 (%build)
`


I downloaded ncurses-5.3.tar.gz from the ncurses website https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#other_versions, along with the associated path file patch-5.3-5.4.sh.gz located here https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#where_patches. I was expecting ncurses to build successfully, to resolve my linker error associated with the bluez-5.65 package. I wasn't expecting the build to fail for a file generated by an ncurses script.

You overlooked bug-reporting as the proper venue.
